# City selection on UberCart checkout menu?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I want users to be able to select a City from a dropdown list when checking out with UberCart.

1. Is there a module that offers this?
2. If not, how do I modify this form to include only certain cities as an option?
3. Does the shipping module allow for you to get access to the City information?

Basically, I want to customly calculate the shipping costs based on the City.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a module for this because the list of Cities is huge and ever changing (unlike States).  Look into an integration of Ubercart and CCK so you can set up your own field for this.

I don't know of a module that does this offhand but it should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I did it with a simple form_alter hook.

Comment: Ah well I didn't know if you felt comfortable writing your own module.  Glad to see you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

I used the form_alter hook to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy will the best for cities...